# Using ramda's evolve in redux reducer

Tags: redux, ramda.js

Aloha!

I am trying to change my reducers code using FP techniques (ramda.js)
But I have an issue with Ramda.evolve(). Here is the code: 
(for simplicity I have added two actions to dispatch)

```
/**
 Global reducer:
 Handles state management for global operations
 **/

"use strict";

import initialState from "./initialState";
import * as R from "ramda";
import {
  SET_MODE
} from "../constants/ActionTypes";

let { packages, ...globalState } = initialState;

//currying
const createReducer = (globalState, handlers) => (state = globalState, action) =>
  R.propOr(R.identity, R.prop("type", action), handlers)(state, action);


const handlers = {
  [SET_MODE]: (state, action) =>
    R.evolve(
      {
        mode: action.mode,
        directory: action.directory
      },
      state
    ),
  [TOGGLE_LOADER]: (state, action) => R.assoc("loading", action.loading, state)
};

const reducer = createReducer(globalState, handlers);
export default reducer;
```

(R = Ramda)

R.assoc is working fine, but R.evolve does not.. It does not return the state with the new values, it just returns the default state. 
what I am doing wrong?

http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve

http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> R.evolve does not

This is the signature of evolve

```
 {k: (v → v)} → {k: v} → {k: v}
```

It takes a dictionary of functions. You are passing a dictionary of values. This should work (though is redundant)

```
R.evolve({
  mode: () => action.mode,
  directory: () => action.directory
}, state)
```

**ADD**

If you need to update multiple props at once you could use [`merge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#merge) and its variations.